React Native - Android build errror "Cmake No compatible library found"
Currently I'm working with a React Native project. The project use Expo but there're some modules which can't be runned by Expo Go so we have to use the development build. After run the build command npx expo run:android I've encountered many errors with the following messages:

Execution failed for task ':expo-av:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
[CXX1210] my-project-folder\node_modules\expo-av\android\CMakeLists.txt debug|arm64-v8a : No compatible library found


I've spent 2 days for searching the solution but none of them is work. Below is the error list with the same error but in others module.


This issue might be already resolved here:
#20123
